# View keyword in Solidity

Tags: solidity

What does view mean in this example?
I have never seen this keyword before.

```
function symbol() view returns (string symbol)
```

Comment: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#view-functions

Answer (score 7):

`view` keyword means that function will not modify state of contract, i.e. not modify variables, not emit events etc.